# Getting file path for use by other function using Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I have just started with Tkinter, so please do not judge me on this... I want to get the path to the csv file and then use it without terminating the program. The following code works, however, I exit the program:

```py
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog


root = Tk()
root.title('ask and print path to file')


def get_path():
    global path
    path = filedialog.askopenfile(title = 'Select the .csv file with keywords', filetypes = (('csv files','*.csv'), ('All files', '*.*')))

path_button = Button(root, text = 'Select keywords', command = get_path)
path_button.pack()


button_quit = Button(root, text ='Exit', command = root.quit)
button_quit.pack(side = BOTTOM)


root.mainloop()

print(path.name)
```

The print statement here is just for simplicity (in reality I want to use `pd.read_csv(path.name)` to read the file, make some wrangling an then return changed file).

How to make the `print(path.name)` without exiting GUI on the background?

Comment: The place where you have that `print` cannot be reached until the window is closed (and it will fail if you close the window without ever having selected a file).  You want to do the work with the file from within `get_path()`.

Comment: @jasonharper I thought about doing this, but is there a way to maybe wait until the path is available and then execute the code?

Comment: actually, do u just want to use `filedialog` for the purpose of choosing directory? or is it needed for the working of this app too?

Comment: The path becomes available *during the execution of `get_path()`*.  I don't understand your objection to doing the work with the path right then and there.

Comment: @CoolCloud I actually need to get the path in order to process with the pipeline in the back.

Comment: u only need the path right?u dont need the root, window to even popup?

Comment: @jasonharper Sorry, maybe i was a bit unclear about the "wrangling". It is quite lengthy so I am not sure if it should be done within getting the path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would change the button command to a function which does all of the file code:

```py
# update the button to call a different function
path_button = Button(root, text = 'Select keywords', command = handle_file)

# make a new function to handle everything
def handle_file():
    path = get_path()
    pd.read_csv(path.name)
    # any other stuff

# change this function too, so that it returns a value to "handle_file* rather than setting a global variable
def get_path():
   return filedialog.askopenfile(title = 'Select the .csv file with keywords', filetypes = (('csv files','*.csv'), ('All files', '*.*')))
```

This way you dont use global variables, and your code can perform stuff after you get the file. The essence of this is that you perform your processing code (`pd.read_csv()`) at the same time you get the path.

Comment: Oh, this is actually what I need and could not come up to it myself! Simple and clear - thanks a lot!

Comment: Better check whether the returned path from `get_path()` is None (i.e. `Cancel` button or `X` button on the title bar is clicked).